# Keras model_plot generates random text in figure

Tags: python, keras

I am currently testing some dummy code about CNN.
I created the following tranditional model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding='same', input_shape = (6,6,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding='same', input_shape = (6,6,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding='same', input_shape = (6,6,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding='same', input_shape = (6,6,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Now, I am trying to plot the model using plot_model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file="test.png", dpi=120, show_shapes=True)
```

However, the generated output figure includes random text that does not make sense for me:

[image]

I trying reinstalling the pydot and pydotplus again:

```
conda uninstall pydot
conda uninstall pydotplus
conda install pydot
conda install pydotplus
```

However, no progress. Any help with that?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Window 11 Pro 22H2